# Is there a way for me to set up virtual environment without having the error below?

Tags: django, windows, virtualenv

**Error installing virtualenv on windows:**

```
PS C:\Users\Jereh Lomak\Desktop\django tutorials> py -m venv myenv
    
Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\Jereh Lomak\\Desktop\\django tutorials\\myenv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

PS C:\Users\Jereh Lomak\Desktop\django tutorials>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for pip install -->   python -m pip install -U pip

for virtualenvwrapper-win install --> pip install virtualenvwrapper-win

create virtualEnvironment --> mkvirtualenv <VirtualEnvironmentName>

Activate  virtualEnvironment --> workon <VirtualEnvironmentName>

deActivate virtualEnvironment  --> deactivate
```

Comment: create virtualEnvironment --> mkvirtualenv <VirtualEnvironmentName> I tried this and here is the result ... PS C:\Users\Jereh Lomak\Desktop\django tutorials> mkvirtualenv myenv
'"virtualenv"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Run pip uninstall virtualenv and then pip install virtualenv